# Required if greater than 0 not working in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.1

I required one field if another field value is greater than 0.

I tried like this

```
'scope' => 'required_if:project,>,1',
```

This code is working if project field value is == 1 but if project value is == 2 then it's not worked

Please give me proper solution

Answer (score 5):

From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-if):

> **required_if:anotherfield,value,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the
>   anotherfield field is equal to any value.

You cannot, therefore, use the `>` comparison with the values you pass. You have two options, in my view. Either you 1) invert the logic of the requirement, in case the values below 1 are very limited (i.e. the number can be either 0 or 1, but never below zero) or you create a custom validation rule.

Here's how the first option would look:

```
'scope' => 'required_unless:project,0,1',
```

Which means: "scope" is only required if project is not 0 or 1 (or greater than 1). Again, this would only work if project cannot be less than zero, or any decimal between 0 and 1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following :

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'project' => 'required|integer',
]);

$v->sometimes('scope', 'required', function ($input) {
    return $input->project > 0;
});
```

> hope that it is not too late ! I searched for the same question then i found this solution

for more info ! [check this link to Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `gt` operator like this

```
'scope' => 'required_if:project,gt,1'
```

Comment: what mean gt operator ?

Comment: @xpredo gt = great than, [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-gt)

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way – move validation to separate file.

### 1 Step: Generate request

```
php artisan make:request StoreScope
```

### 2 Step: Edit validation rules

File */app/Http/Requests/StoreScope.php*

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreScope extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'scope' => 'nullable|integer',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Configure the validator instance.
     *
     * @param Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator
     * @return void
     */
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->sometimes('scope', 'required', function($input) {
            return $input->project > 1;
        });
    }
}
```

### 3 Step: Check validation in controller

File */app/Http/Controllers/ScopeController.php*

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreOrder;

class ScopeController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param StoreOrder $request
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function storeAction(StoreOrder $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();

        print_r($data);
        die;
    }
}
?>
```